# rails strip non numeric values before save

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have searched and it looks like this should be simple but I can't get it to work.  I am trying to remove all non-numeric characters prior to saving a phone number.  This is what I have currently:

```
before_save { |workorder| workorder.phonenumber = 
                  phonenumber.to_s.gsub(/\D/, '').to_i }
```

So if a user inputs

```
925-555-5555
```

It should save 9255555555 but it is actually saving only 925 and ignoring everything after

I also tried:

```
before_save { |workorder| workorder.phonenumber = 
                  phonenumber.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9]/, "").to_i }
```

with the same result.

Solved:

```
def raw_phonenumber
  self.phonenumber
end
def raw_phonenumber=(s)
  self.phonenumber=s.gsub(/\D/, '')
end
```

Comment: Should be `workorder.phonenumber.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9]/, "").to_i` ??  You're missing the `workorder`  (if that's your actual code)

Comment: what data type is phonenumber?

Comment: Your input is being cast to an integer because of your db table: "925-555-5555".to_i #=> 925

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You certainly have defined the `phonenumber` column as number. That's why when you set `'925-555-5555'` in the `phonenumber` attribute, it is casted to a number, and only `925` is kept.

The best solution is to change the type of the column in your database to `string`. Create a new migration:

```
change_column :table_name, :phonenumber, :string, limit: 30
```

Otherwise, you can override the setter like this to remove the non numeric characters (**but it won't fix phone numbers starting with '0's**):

```
def phonenumber=(phonenumber)
  write_attribute(:phonenumber, phonenumber.gsub(/\D/, ''))
end
```

More alternatives in this [blog post](http://blog.arkency.com/2016/01/drop-this-before-validation-and-use-method/)

Comment: i ended up using getter and setter methods based on your solution.

Comment: Maybe it's better to just `super` instead of `write_attribute`.

Comment: According to the documentation, `super` is the way to go. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord%3a%3aBase-label-Overwriting+default+accessors

Comment: Upvoting for storing phone number as a string. It isn't a number that you would do math on and not storing as a string causes more headaches than it is worth.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do it is by mutating the `field=` method:

```
def field=(value)
  super(value.delete('^0-9'))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom method for save/display mobile number like this:

```
def mobile_number(arg)

if arg.downcase.include?('special chars')

phone_number = arg.downcase.split('special chars')

phone = if phone_number[0].to_i == 0 || phone_number[0].to_i.to_s.size < 10
number_to_phone(phone_number[0].gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '').to_i, area_code: true)
else
number_to_phone(phone_number[0].to_i, area_code: true)
end

return phone.to_s + ' Ext'+ remove_unnecessary_keywords(phone_number[1])

elsif arg.include?('(') || arg.include?(')') || arg.include?('-') || 
arg.include?('.') || arg.include?(' ')

return  number_to_phone(arg.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '').to_i, area_code: true)    

else

return number_to_phone(arg.to_i, area_code: true) 

end

end
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.